# Flow Type + Redux: Type for action that won't conflict with actions for other reducers

Tags: redux, flowtype

I have a reducer for storing preferences. It has two action types. One for loading in all preferences from database and another for updating a single preference. I have a working standalone example but it breaks once used inside of my app.

The issue is that my preferences reducer only handles two types of actions, while my app has multiple reducers that fire other actions. A solution to get the code running is to add a third general type for actions not related to this reducer. That however creates `Property not found in 'object type'.` errors when I try to access properties of the action.

[Working flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1AGQPICCAIgPoAKASgKIBiAyqfQKoDCr199oAvKAOQESFGgyZsOXfgG4U6bKGblihACrURdXgKUr1m2jMSIsATwAOAU1ABDVRet8A3olCgA1GasAuUNgBOAJZoAOaIAL6yiJYAHuaw-jhe1jbIWIHo9lbaLm6eDr7JsJB4RGRUdIws7Jz0ADSuoOb+lpAYvoT+-jamADxOpIEAJr4BwSF1oABuNtAArpa+Nmim4QB8EaAAPqC5HsmFDsWKymoaFbQNbsOjWEGhV9OzC0srEVGx8YmgQ602c9AcAAKbA2LCLXbhHLhSapdLoJZpDJoLKWACUvDWu0aGHggSwyAAFqAgXDkQA6ZIYvZuZA2DDWITlURVCS1Xw0tygVCYHBoSzwehYMGOSGyLlcsnocnNVoYcmQBLUVKEoHmTHYiUS-mC4XggDa5nJgyGAF1tEaZvNLOKteE0baJS0sHN-GhQDqhSLHaBwo1afTrLozgYOf6uc7Xe6nKByXHQeDJvqpWhycNTYj4amrQtfT6-RLfpB-oDvOG3JG3X49TbGn7IkA)

```
// @flow
const LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS = 'LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS';
const UPDATE_PREF = 'UPDATE_PREF';

type aType = {
  +type: string
};

export type actionType = {
  +type: typeof LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS,
  prefs: Array<{_id: string, value: any}>
} | {
  +type: typeof UPDATE_PREF,
  id: string,
  value: any
};

export default (state: {} = {}, action: actionType) => {
  if (action.type === LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS) {
    action.prefs.forEach(p => {
      console.log(p);
    });
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS: {
      const newState = {};
      action.prefs.forEach(p => {
        newState[p._id] = p.value;
      });
      return newState;
    }
    case UPDATE_PREF: {
      return { ...state, [action.id]: action.value };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is valid flow but when the app actually runs, I get an error when an action with type `INIT_APP` or something runs. The error says `action must be one of:` and then it lists the two types I have in `actionType` as the expected and an actual of `{ type: string }`.

I can get the app running by adding a third type to `actionType` like this:

```
export type actionType = {
  +type: typeof LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS,
  prefs: Array<{_id: string, value: any}>
} | {
  +type: typeof UPDATE_PREF,
  id: string,
  value: any
} | {
  +type: string
};
```

Even though the app now runs without error, it does not pass flow type check. Throwing errors of `Property not found in object type`. [Here is an example on flow.org](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1AGQPICCAIgPoAKASgKIBiAyqfQKoDCr199oAvKAOQESFGgyZsOXfgG4U6bKGblihACrURdXgKUr1m2jMSIsATwAOAU1ABDVRet8A3olCgA1GasAuUNgBOAJZoAOaIAL6yiJYAHuaw-jhe1jbIWIHo9lbaLm6eDr7JsJB4RGRUdIws7Jz0ADSuoOb+lpAYvoT+-jamADxOpIEAJr4BwSF1oABuNtAArpa+Nmim4QB8EaAAPqC5HsmFDsWKymoaFbQNbsOjWEGhV9OzC0srmzt7+T5+d+MRUbF4olQENWjY5tAcAAKbA2LCLXbhHLhSapdLoJZpDJoLKWACUvDWu0aGHggSwyAAFqAoWjsQA6ZIEvZuZA2DDWITlURVCS1XwstygVCYHBoSzwehYOGORGyIVCunoenNVoYemQBLUVKUqHmQnEhUK8WS6XwgDa5npgyGAF1tFaZvNLPKjeE8a6FS0sHN-GhQCapTLPaBwo1WezrLozgYBeGhd7ff6nKB6WnYfDJualWh6cNbZj0bmnQtQyGwwrQZBwZDvPG3Im-T9g40w5EgA)

Answer (score 0):

Since every reducer ends up seeing every action, you'll want the type of this reducer function to include all the possible actions in your app. I usually define a single variant `actionType` with everything available in the app and use that in every reducer.

The reason why your last code example doesn't work is because the third, anonymous action type `{type: string}` is too vague. Before this, Flow could look at the two options in the action, and see that it would know which one was which based on the `case` statements. But with the third action type, an action like `{type: "LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS"}` would match the third case in the type. So testing `action.type === LOAD_PREFS_SUCCESS` is no longer enough to prove that the action will have a `prefs` key.

So there are two ways to fix this:

1. If you change your action type to be more specific and include all the specific action types, your reducer should go back to type-checking.
2. Otherwise, add a dummy case, like `| {type: "NOT-REAL"}` so that Flow forces your reducer to have a default case for actions it doesn't understand.

Comment: Thanks Adam, so I would need to create actionTypes for every single action and possibly store it in its own file or in my root reducer file. This sounds extremely cumbersome especially when I consider some of the libraries I use that also hook into the redux state like react-router and react-redux-form. Is there a good way around this or are my options to type everything or stop using flow?

Comment: Well, its going to be hard to give a type to the action parameter of this reducer without having a way to refer to the types of the actions. You could replace `type: string` with `type: 'A' | 'B' | ...` just too list the other types. Then as you add logic that uses each action type, break it out and declare the types of data that action will have.

Comment: looks like you are also involved over on github and answered my issue over there with a working solution :D Want to toss it up on here so I can give you the answer cred and hopefully help others that run into this in the future? Thanks!